# How do I vertically center my image?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a page here - http://click2recycle.ca/. If you look at the section under the headline "FREE PICK UP AND RECYCLING OF LARGE QUANTITIES OF ELECTRONICS", there is picture of a truck. It is vertically centered at the midpoint of the images on its left and right.

I also have a page here - http://vmmed.com/service/?page_id=7. If you look at the section under the headline "OUR ACCREDITATIONS AND AFFILIATIONS", you will see a logo for an organization called CAR (the middle logo). It is not vertically centered at the midpoint of the images on its left and right despite my best efforts.

I have compared the CSS using Chrome's Inspect Element function but I can't seem to find the difference.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Their png's have extra transparent height I believe in the first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people are commenting about fixes, but I think the original question asks WHY the two are different. I found the same and was interested as well (using Chrome) why the two were behaving differently.

First, here are the differences (using Chrome) - I've added a red border to visually show that they're not top-aligned.

http://vmmed.com/service/?page_id=7

[image]

and http://click2recycle.ca/

[image]

Now, when you view the two pages in Firefox, you see:

[image]

and

[image]

Again, both of these were from Firefox and show that they ARE both top-aligned. So what's the difference?

That's when I noticed an `inline style` on one page (http://click2recycle.ca/) and not on the other:

```
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
```

(Info about box-align here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-align)

[image]

And that's why the two are different! (And why it's specific to Chrome - because of the vendor prefix).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do it. 
The simplest is probably add padding-top to its containing div and take it away with a media query(noticed it was responsive) at a certain screen resolution.

alternatively, have a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div) which I have used successfully a few times, but it's kind of tricky to get everything just right in all browsers with empty elements and using `display:inline`

Answer (score 0):

add the css

```
top:30px;
```

to the element with Xpath:

```
//*[@id="x-content-band-10"]/div[2]
```

(div with classes **"x-column vc one-third"**)

Answer (score 0):

This fixes it and should leave it responsive. Drop this in the CSS

```
.center-block {
margin-top: 2.25em;
```